# How can we reload custom dojo widget

Tags: dojo

I've a custom dojo widget (reminder )which I want to reload on an event(on click of add button on widget a dialog will open where I'll fill reminder data and will click submit . on click of submit button widget should reload with data which I filled in dialog).

```html
<body class="claro teller">

         <form name="tellerForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="expldQryStr" id="expldQryStr">
                 <input type="hidden" name="actionCode" id="actionCode">
         </form>

        <div class="row">

                <div data-dojo-type="MyCashBalanceWidget.MyCashBalance" data-dojo-props="title:'Our Cash Balance Widget',data:CashBalData,data1:invtData"></div>
                <div data-dojo-type="MyFrequentTasksWidget.MyFrequentTasks"     data-dojo-props="pageName:'TellerLandingPage',title:'Our Some Widget',data:freqTskData"></div>
                <div data-dojo-type="PendingTransactionWidget.PendingTransaction" data-dojo-props="title:'Pending Transaction Widget',data:pndTrnData,data1:pndVrfData"></div>
                <div id="remWdgt" data-dojo-type="MyRemindersWidget.MyReminders"        data-dojo-props="pageName:'TellerLandingPage',title:'My Reminders Widget',data:rmndrData"></div>
                <div data-dojo-type="MyAppsWidget.MyApps" data-dojo-props="pageName:'TellerLandingPage',title:'My Apps Widget'"></div>
                <div data-dojo-type="MyActivityWidget.MyActivity" data-dojo-props="pageName:'TellerLandingPage',title:'My Activity Widget',data:analData"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-dojo-type="TellerLandingPageGridWidget.TellerLandingPageGrid" data-dojo-props="title:'Teller Landing grid',data:lastTrans">
        </div>

        <script>
                //including all the custom widgets
                require(
                                [
                                                "dojo/parser",
                                                "CommonWidgets/MyFrequentTasksWidget",
                                                "Widgets/MyCashBalanceWidget",
                                                "Widgets/PendingTransactionWidget",
                                                "CommonWidgets/MyRemindersWidget",
                                                "CommonWidgets/MyAppsWidget",
                                                "CommonWidgets/MyActivityWidget",
                                                "Widgets/TellerLandingPageGridWidget"
                                ],
                                function( parser) {
                                        parser.parse();
                                });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

please suggest how can I reload dojo widget  .

Comment: Here I want to reload CommonWidgets/MyRemindersWidget widget

Comment: Try to post a minimal example of what you're trying to do, the HTML you now posted does nothing, does not run and doesn't give an actual idea of what you're trying. My best guess is that you have a widget A in which you enter data and widget B in which you would like to show the data if it's submit. But I can't find anything of that in your code.

Comment: Or you have a widget with a dialog and if you submit, then in the same widget it should show that data, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your complete scenario. But in such situation, you have two ways:-
1) Add event listener to your custom widget, that will listen and modify itself
2) Recreate the widget, passing it's constructor with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, but from the sound of it, you just want to set the `innerHTML` of a specific DOM node if a form within a dialog is submit. There's no reason to reload the widget for that, you could just add an event handler to the submit event of the dialog form, and use that to set the `innerHTML` of a specific element inside your widget.

First of all you need to add an `onLoad` event listener to your dialog so you know exactly when to add the event handlers to the form:

```
postCreate: function() {
    this.myDialog = new Dialog();
    this.myDialog.on("load", lang.hitch(this, this.loadDialog));
    this.myDialog.set("content", "<div><form><input type='text' /><button type='submit'>Submit</button></div>");
},
```

This will call a function `loadDialog` on your widget, which could look like this:

```
loadDialog: function() {
    var vm = this;
    query("form", this.myDialog.domNode).on("submit", function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        vm.myLabel.innerHTML = query("input", this).val();
        vm.myDialog.hide();
    });
},
```

This function utilizes `dojo/query` and `dojo/NodeList-manipulate` to obtain the form field value when the form inside the dialog is submit. That value is then used to alter `myLabel` an element on the widget that I gave the attribute `data-dojo-attach-point="myLabel"` so that it's easily accessible from within the widget code:

```
templateString: "<div><label data-dojo-attach-point='myLabel'></label><button data-dojo-attach-event='onClick: openDialog'>Add</button></div>",
```